# SElinux enforcing status is different from the config file

Tags: linux, command-line, security, selinux

Deal All

I have a problem with SELinux. 
In the config file SELINUX=enforcing
but when i run getenforcing command i get disabled. 
I rebooted the server to see if there is any changes but stil the same 
What exactly is the problem??

Answer (score 1):

So your SELinux config looks like this

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of three two values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

But when you run `getenforce` the result is `Disabled`.

Things you need to check:

- The SELinux config is in the right place (on RHEL based this is `/etc/selinux/config`)
- There are no kernel command line arguments that disable SELinux
- There is no rc.d line that runs `setenforce 0`

Generally one of these will usually be the cause. Also make sure you write out the file when you do edit it (with VIM this is `:wq`, with nano <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>)

In the mean time you can mitigate this using `setenforce 1`

Answer (score 0):

To make changes persistent through a system reboot, edit the 'SELINUX=' line in `/etc/selinux/config` for either 'enforcing', 'permissive', or 'disabled'. For example: `SELINUX=permissive`